# Connecting NEO 6m GPS to a Pi running Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, gps

I am working on connecting a NEO 6m GPS to my Pi which is running Raspbian Jessie.

I followed some tutorials and I am sure the serial ports are connected to ttyAMA0 using `ls -l /dev`. The GPS is blanking but when i try `gpsmon` it results in  `unknown device`. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How is the module interfaced with RPi physically? All that is required are Vcc,GND, Tx from the GPS.